# Removing a DataGridViewRow from a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
Dim Count As Integer = 1
For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgv1stSem.Rows
    If dgv1stSem.Item(1, Count).Value = vbNullString Then
        dgv1stSem.Rows.Remove(Row)
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
Next
```

I'm trying to remove a series of rows without a value in a certain cell in the row when I click a button. But when I click the button, not all is removed.

Comment: What are you doing with the variable `Row` in the `For Each` statement?

Comment: I saw an example in google using that loop to search in the datagrid. I put the `Row` to be the index that will be deleted.

Comment: First: each loop, you are checking the same row in your DataGridView. You should use `Row` instead of `dgv1stSem` in your If-Statement. Second: this may cause problems at runtime, if there are two rows with a vbNullString so to speak in a row. Try to loop through your DataGridView from the end to the beginning.

Comment: I changed the code with the `Row` instead of dgv1stsem and it deleted some of the rows without values. It takes up to 4 to 5 clicks to remove all rows without values. But I need it to be 1 click only.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about :-) Loop backward through your DGV should do it.

Comment: What do you mean by loop backward? Im lost, im sorry. I dont understand

Comment: Begin at the last row and loop backwards ;-) You will need something like that to do this: `For rowid As Integer = dgv1stSem.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1`

Comment: It did it. Thank you so much.